# Deserializing guava optional<long> is failing

Tags: jackson, jackson-databind

I am serializing a guava optional using jackson(version:2.9.4).

When i am deserializing, i am getting below exception:

```
Cannot deserialize instance of 'java.lang.Long' out START_OBJECT token.
```

When i debug the value during deserialization, i noticed that the value is coming as "Optional(present=true)" rather than the value present inside Optional.

I looked at the object mapper, and "GuavaModule()" is already being registered with the object mapper. 
Please let me know if i am missing anything.

Comment: What do you mean with 'Option'? Optional? Just a typo?

Comment: @mle its a typo. I meant, i was losing the value at time of deserialization

Comment: You may want to try `2.9.5` which was just released (see https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.9.5) -- there is one fix to Guava module that might be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With registering the GuavaModule of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-guava</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

…and the following bean…

```
import com.google.common.base.Optional;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class GuavaBean {
    private Optional<Long> abc;
}
```

…this gives me a green test…

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.guava.GuavaModule;
[…]
@Test
public void guava() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException  {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new GuavaModule());

    GuavaBean bean = new GuavaBean(Optional.of(9l));
    String beanSerialized = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(bean);
    assertThat(beanSerialized).isEqualTo("{\"abc\":9}");

    GuavaBean optLong = objectMapper.readValue(beanSerialized, GuavaBean.class);
    assertThat(optLong.getAbc().get()).isEqualTo(9);
}
```

However, if I accidentally use `java.util.Optional` instead of `com.google.common.base.Optional`, then the beahviour is exactly like you wrote.

Comment: What you have above is pretty straight forward. I was talking about the case where we do "objectMapper.writeValue(new GuavaBean(Optional.of(4L))", and then doing readValue from it

Comment: Sorry my fault... but also your case, if I now understand it correctly, works for me; as shown in my updated snippet above.

Comment: ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        om.registerModule(new GuavaModule());
        TestBean tb = new TestBean();
        tb.setVal(Optional.of(2L));
String str = om.writeValueAsString(tb);
        System.out.print("Serialized.. -> "+str);
        

Serialized.. -> {"val":{"present":true}}

Comment: I am using jackson-2.9.4 jars. And, when i serialize, the value is lost. {present:true} is getting printed. thats where the problem lies i guess.

Comment: I am also using 2.9.4. Could you double-check that your jackson-core, jackson-databind and jackson-datatype-guava libs are in sync regarding their version?

Comment: Weird... you code here gives ```Serialized.. -> {"abc":2}```

Comment: Yeah, i have checked all the 4 jars, jackson-core, jackson-annotations, jackson-databind, jackson-datatype-guava are on 2.9.4. Thats strange why its not working for me :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167579/discussion-between-venkataratnam-and-mle).

Comment: Because I did not see you in the chat may be one last time here:
If I am not using Guava optionals but rather ```import java.util.Optional;``` then I can reproduce your output.
So, could you take a look that all your optionals are really ```com.google.common.base.Optional```?